# NOT IN Select statement returning 0 values

Tags: sql, teradata

I have data with variables ID and Code.  Sample data shown below:

```
ID   Code
abc  00
def  00
ghi  00
def  23
jkl  00
mno  20 
pqr  24
```

ID can have multiple values of different codes.  I am trying to work out all possible combinations of code per ID (there are 15 in total)

My code:

```
select id, code from data.test 
where id in (select id from data.test where code = 00 )
and id in ('abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr')
```

works fine (returning 4 rows) however  this code:

```
select id, code from data.test 
where id not in (select id from data.test where code = 23)
and id in ('abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr')
```

returns 0 rows? It should return 3 rows.

I am using Teradata SQL Assistant version 15.00.0.02.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should return 5 rows - all except `def 23`. This clearly isn't your real code; I think something has been lost in simplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason why `not in` with a subquery fails is because one of the values (`id` in your case) is `NULL`.  In this case, the `NOT IN` expression never returns true.  One way to fix this:

```
select id, code
from data.test 
where id not in (select id from data.test where code = 23 and id is not null) and
      id in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr')
```

Another way is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.id, t.code
from data.test t
where not exists (select 1 from data.test t2 where t.code = 23 and t2.id = t.id) and
      t.id in ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr')
```

Comment: In Teradata one should prefer `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN`

Comment: @dnoeth . . . I generally prefer `NOT EXISTS` precisely because of the semantic difference (and happily it often works better than `NOT IN`).